# Which Encoding is used for Exported Reference Data?

Tags: enterprise-architect

**Question**

How is the information in the exported reference data for Automation Scripts encoded/calculated using Enterprise Architect's built-in "Export Reference Data" functionality? Is it just some proprietary EA standard encoding?

**More information**

Here a snippet of what I've got in the exported .xml for my script:

```
<Column name="ScriptID" value="52"/>
<Column name="ScriptCategory" value="605A62F7-BCD0-4845-A8D0-7DC45B4D2E3F"/>
<Column name="ScriptName" value="{819A60C0-9188-4d44-8CDD-999A9B47C9FD}"/>
```

How is the `value` field calculated for `ScriptCategory` and `ScriptName`?

For reference, `ScriptCategory` should be equal to "`UserScript`" and `ScriptName` is equal to "`ConfigureMKS`".

Answer (score 2):

They reflect values from columns of the table `t_script`.

Open the SQL scratch pad (Ctrl-F and then depending on your EA version...) and enter

```
SELECT * from t_script
```

Then you will see the GUIDs from the export in the columns with the name as the attribute `value`.

*Note*: I will refrain from commenting on the data format which is being used by Sparx.